# When I am stressed

Tags: riddle

When I am stressed,

I can say so much more,

I'm three times within myself,

Twice Window, Once door.

What am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Syllable -- it has three syllables, window has two, door has one. Syllables can be stressed.

Comment: Well done, that's the correct answer! :)